# PyQt4- How can I make a button to remove a selected item in a ComboBox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I am making a GUI for a program and needed people to add items to a list to select from. That worked, but I figured they might want to remove and item because they changed their mind. So I want to make a button that achieves just that.

```
......class code and stuff
self.delFuncBttn.clicked.connect(lambda:self.delFunc) #The button that I want to delete the selected item
badFunc = self.funcCB.currentText() #This is how i retrieve the currently selected text
funCB.removeItem(badFunc)#Trying to remove it with this method I found in the documentation
```

Is there another method to do what I want or am I using the method wrong? Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. I would put the whole code but it is a lot and a bit messy I suppose. What I give is what I am using to try to get what I want done.

Answer (score 1):

`QComboBox.removeItem()` expects an integer denoting the index of the item to remove. It does not expect the text of the item to remove. You can get the current index using `self.funcCB.currentIndex()`. Passing that to `removeItem()` should make your code work.

Comment: I did this ...it wont let me indent.                                                                    def delFunc(self): /n  
  badFunc = self.funcCB.currentText()/n  
  p = self.funcCB.currentIndex(badFunc)/n  

  funcCB.removeItem(p)